# How do I generate a websocket handshake from Lua?

Tags: lua, websocket, handshake

Is there an existing function to generate the server response key in Lua?  Here is the solution in python: [websocket handshake problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220547/websocket-handshake-problem)

I do have the two key numbers captured, the spaces counted, the third string captured and hoping the rest lies in an existing function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need the older handshake (protocol 0), you can use the following code to get the handshake value from the two keys:

```
md5 = require 'md5'

function getnumbers(str)
    local num = ""
    str:gsub('%d', function(d) num = num .. d end)
    return tonumber(num)
end
function countspaces(str)
    return select(2, str:gsub(' ', ' '))
end
function to32bitint(i)
    return string.char(i/256^3 % 256, i/256^2 % 256, i/256 % 256, i % 256)
end
function websocketresponse(key1, key2, end8)
    local n1, s1 = getnumbers(key1), countspaces(key1)
    local n2, s2 = getnumbers(key2), countspaces(key2)
    local cat = to32bitint(n1/s1) .. to32bitint(n2/s2) .. ending8
    return md5.sum(cat)
end

websocket_key1 = "18x 6]8vM;54 *(5:  {   U1]8  z [  8"
websocket_key2 = "1_ tx7X d  <  nw  334J702) 7]o}` 0"
ending8 = "Tm[K T2u"
print(websocketresponse(websocket_key1, websocket_key2, ending8))
--> fQJ,fN/4F4!~K~MH
```

This produces the same value as the example given in [the protocol draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-socket-protocol/). This example uses [MD5](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) library to calculate the checksum and is available compiled in [LuaForWindows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/).

The implementation for WebSocket protocol version 6 is much simpler:

```
crypto = require 'crypto'
mime = require 'mime'

function websocketresponse6(key)
    local magic = key .. "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
    return (mime.b64(crypto.digest('sha1', magic, true)))
end 

key6 = "x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw=="
print(websocketresponse6(key6))
--> HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
```

This example uses the [LuaCrypto](https://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto) for SHA1 sum and [MIME](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/mime.html) from LuaSocket.

Comment: I am using Lua within a Windows application.  The distribution does not include crypto (or the % math operator, but math.mod works so that part is resolved).  Is there a work around for not having crypto?  Safari and Mobile Safari are both using the older protocol 0.

Comment: I do not know which Lua distribution you are using, but I guess that it is [Lua For Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/). It contains a [MD5](http://www.keplerproject.org/md5/manual.html#reference) library compiled, I will update the code for it.

Comment: I don't have the md5 library either.  I am not sure how to add it with the interpreter only available within the application.  (I've requested the developer to add either library.)  I can fix these (only because I understand this portion), but neither **str:gsub('%d', function(d) num = num .. d end)** nor **select(2, str:gsub(' ', ' '))** will execute within the application...

Comment: What version of Lua are you using? This should work in Lua 5.1, which is around since early 2006. In the meantime, you can try this: `string.gsub(str, '%d', ...)` and `local _,n = string.gsub(str, ' ', ' '); return n`

Comment: Then use the code I provided (I just changed `str:gsub(...` to `string.gsub(str,...` and replaced the `select` call with equivalent Lua code). If you do not have a module for MD5 and cannot compile libraries, you can find pure Lua MD5 implementations [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083262/pure-lua-implementation-of-md5).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7926/discussion-between-shaun5-and-michal-kottman)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [lua-websockets implementation](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets/blob/master/src/websocket/handshake.lua). Here is the [sha1 stuff](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets/blob/master/src/websocket/tools.lua).